# How to set image quality to high in canvas2image

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

When I take screen png the image is lower in this code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
   <head>
      <div class="specific">
         <title>Click to Take a Screenshot & Download it!</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
   <h1>Click to Take a Screenshot & Download it! <small>using html2canvas.js + canvas2image.js</small>
   </h1>        <p>         مثال        </p>  
   <p>
   Use html2canvas.js to take a screenshot of a specific div and then use canvas2image.js to download the screenshot as an image
   locally to your filesystem.       </p>
   <button type="button" class="btn
      btn-default">Take a Screenshot!</button>   <p>References:  <a
      href="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/">html2canvas.js</a>
   <a
      href="https://github.com/SuperAL/canvas2image">canvas2image.js</a>
   </p>
   </div>
   <script src='js/html2canvas.min.js'/>
      <script
      src='js/canvas2image.js'>
   </script>
   <script>
      document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            html2canvas(document.querySelector('.specific'), {
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    // document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                  return Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
                }
            });
        }); 
   </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I want to set image quality and size.

Comment: Why did you reject [tinamou's edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/3199972)?

Comment: I've restored the good edit made to this, and would regard your rollback as vandalism, Majed. Noting your edit message, helpful contributors do not need your permission to edit questions here. If that is a problem for you, then Stack Overflow may not be compatible with the kind of site you want.

Comment: Readers will appreciate it if you could refrain from txtspk here also, since writing using real English words makes things easier to read for everyone. This is not Facebook.